# Rendering other components through an <a> link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the example below, I have two functional components that give the idea of being separate pages, though, of course, they only display different colored `<div>` boxes.

```
const Home = () =>
    <div style={{background:'red', height: 100, width: 100}}></div>;

const About = () =>
    <div style={{background:'blue', height: 100, width: 100}}></div>;
```

Now, if I wanted to create a navigation bar that links to certain parts of my site -- ignoring the possible wrong use of the `<a>` links, but it is to show that I want those to render other parts of the site as a response to clicking on a `Navbar` option.

```
const Navbar = () =>
    <div>
        <a href='#'>Home</a>
        <a href='#'>About</a>
    </div>;
```

If I have a component named `App` that renders different pages for me:

```
const App = () =>
    <div>
        <Navbar />
        // Render current page here; default is the `Home` component.
    </div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

How could I actively update my `App` component to render different pages based off the clicking of links, or elements, in my `Navbar`?

EDIT:
[Soviut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46914/soviut) and [finalfreq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4574285/finalfreq), thank you for your answers! I came from Codecademy's ReactJS course, so the transition into the 'real world' of Javascript and React has been somewhat difficult, since I've had to learn about ES6, and being ignorant of most JS libraries. Anyway, I appreciate that you guys pointed me in the direction of `react-router` and gave me an example on how to achieve my goal without it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) was built to do.

While doing it manually isn't recommended, it would work by emitting click events that call a callback function passed into it from a parent component that contains your "pages". That callback would tell the parent container which navigation link was clicked and it would decide which page to show and which to stop rendering.

Answer (score 1):

absent of a router/controller for each page, you could do something like:

```
const pages = ['array', 'of', 'pages'];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activePage: pages[0]
    }
  }

  switchPage = (page) => {
    this.setState({
    activePage: page
    })
  }

  renderActivePage = () => {
    switch(this.state.activePage) {
      case 'home': 
        return <HomeComponent />
    }
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
       <Navbar switchPageFunction={this.switchPage}/>
       {renderActivePage()}
       </div>;)
  }

}
```

and then just set the onclick to your a tags to actually be the switchPageFunction and pass in the page name as an argument. Then the parent component will receive the update, update its own state, and render the correct component.

I don't suggest this route and would instead look into react-router which is built just for this use case